# Question about inclusion of orthogonal of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{v_1, . . . , v_k \}$ be the orthogonal set generated in the course
of applying the Gram–Schmidt process to a basis, and define
$S_j = span\{v_1, . . . , v _j \}$ for $j = 1, . . . , k
$

> (a) Prove that if $ i < j$ , then $S_i$ is a subspace of $S_ j $.
>
> (b) Prove that if $i < j$ , then $S_j^{\perp}$ is a subspace of $S_i^{\perp}$ where $S_i^{\perp}$ and $S_j^{\perp}$ is the set of all vectors orthogonal to respective $S_i$ or $S_j.$

---

What I did so far:

I tried to prove part a by proving $S_i$ is a subspace of $S_j $by showing the 3 properties of subspaces.

1) 0 vector is in both because you can rewrite the span with all coefficients 0 which results in 0

2) 2 vectors r and t in $S_i$, when added are in $S_i$ as well as $S_j
$

3) A vector r in $S_i$, when multiplied by any constant, is still in $S_i$ as well as $S_j.
$

Not sure how to really progress from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Begin by showing that $S_j^\perp$ is a subset of $S_i^\perp$. To do this, let $v\in S_j^\perp$. Then by definition $\langle v,v_\ell\rangle = 0$ for all $\ell = 1,\ldots,j$. Since $i < j$ it follows that $v\in S_i^\perp$. Thus $S_j^\perp\subset S_i^\perp$. Now you can use similar arguments to prove that $S_j^\perp$ is a subspace of $S_i^\perp$ by verifying that

1. $0\in S_j^\perp$
2. If $u,v\in S_j^\perp$, then $u + v \in S_j^\perp$.
3. If $v\in S_j^\perp$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then $\alpha v \in S_j^\perp$.